# Reading a file using node.js in ES 6

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've the following object that reads a file,

```
import {fs} from '../../node_modules/node/fs';

class Reader{

    constructor(path){
        this._path = path;
    }

    printFile(){
        fs.readFile(this._path, (err, data) =>{
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(data);
        })
    }
}
```

Now I want to write another file, ES6 standard that instantiates this object, and calls it print method which would print the data on the screen.
I want to pass in the filename as a parameter.
In sense I want to run this program in the following way.

```
node main.js filename.txt
```

Comment: To get command line arguments, you probably want [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv).  Also, you may want to know that using a `throw` in an async callback will rarely do anything useful with regards to your error handling.

Comment: Well as I said I'm new to js, could you write up some boiler plate to get me started.

Comment: Did you look at the link I included in my comment.  There are examples there.  It seems you should read the linked doc (rather than me repeating it), try something and come back here if/when you get stuck.

Comment: I think I understand the `process.argv` call. But that call will be on a main.js file which will then pass on the string path to the `Reader` object. What I need is some help in boilerplating the  main.js. Could you help.

Comment: The way stack overflow works best is if you try to figure it out, write some code, debug what you have and then post your code when you got stuck and explain exactly what you got stuck on.  You will actually learn it better that way too.  We aren't supposed to be a code writing service that just writes it for you.

Comment: BTW, you can (and should) just say `import {fs} from 'fs';`. Anyway, what is the point of going to all this work to wrap `fs.readFile` in a new-fangled class?

Comment: `console.log` will mangle files that come through in multiple pieces of `data` because it adds newlines. Try writing to the process stdout.